# Please help me understand how to make my first jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

As the title suggests, I am new to web design. 
I was hoping to make a website that would be cross platform & browser friendly (mobile, tablets, desktop, etc.). Currently I am using Microsoft's Expression Web 4 to be like training wheels if I ever decide to get Adobe Dreamweaver (if it's worth it).

After watching videos and searching for different kinds of image sliders I cannot understand what I am missing for some of the forms, ids, etc. that seem to be standard jquery. Having said that, I am unsure how to make my own external js page for a basic flashing or even a standard slide-in image slider.

If anyone is willing to help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Additional info:
html 5, css 2.1, and webpage size at 900px wide though using Google's suggested HTML script to scale viewing size.

**html**

```
<head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title> Bear's Den Lodge Home </title>
    <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bDL-jquery.js"></script>
</head> 

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="top">

                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="Images/logov2.png"  />
                </div>


                <div id="social-media">
                    <p>Connect With Us</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bearsdenlodge"> <img src="Images/facebook-icon35p.png" /></a> </li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+BearsDenLodgeAlban">  <img src="Images/google-plus-icon35p.png" /> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/BearsDenFishing"> <img src="Images/twitter-icon35p.png" /> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Fish With Us Today;    Summer: (705).857.2757 <br>
                                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Winter:&nbsp;&nbsp;(814).839.2443  </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="topnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fishing.html"> Fishing &amp; Guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="accommodations.html"> Accommodations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="area.html"> Area &amp; History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rates.html"> Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </div>              

            <div id="banner"> 

                <div id="bannerslider">

                    <ul class="slides"> 
                        <li class="slide"><img id="Image 1" src="Images/bassperfect-900px.png" alt="bassperfect" width="100%"/></li> 
                        <li class="slide"><img id="Image 2" src="Images/chrismuskie.png" alt="muskie" width="100%"/></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img id="Image 3" src="Images/kuntzpike.png" alt="kuntzpike" width="100%"/></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img id="Image 4" src="Images/unitedlumberdinner.png" alt="dinner" width="100%"/></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="subbanner"><h3>Fishing French River, Canada's Premier Fishing Destination. Northeastern ON</h3></div>


            <div id="content">
                <h2> Welcome to Bear's Den Lodge!</h2> <p>We are a seasonal hunting and fishing operator 
located in the French River Delta. Providing clients over the past 30 years 
exceptional family style care. Our dedicated staff are here to ensure your 
satisfaction from the facilities and equipment we provide to the experiences 
and memories made!</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rightside">

                    <h3>French River Forecast</h3>
                    <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="wxButtonFrame" id="wxButtonFrame" height="110" src="http://btn.weather.ca/weatherbuttons/template5.php?placeCode=CAON0007&amp;category0=Cities&amp;containerWidth=150&amp;btnNo=&amp;backgroundColor=blue&amp;multipleCity=0&amp;citySearch=1&amp;celsiusF=F" align="top" frameborder="0" width="150" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    <a href="https://www1.on.wildlifelicense.com/custlkup.php?lang=1https://www1.on.wildlifelicense.com/custlkup.php?lang=1"><h3>Fishing &amp; Hunting Liscense </h3> </a>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy;All rights reserved by Bear's Den Lodge 2001-2015</p>
            </div>

        </div>  

    </body>
```

**CSS**

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Print style */

h1, h2, h3 { 
    font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic;}
 h1 { font-size: 30px;}
 h2 { font-size: 26px;}
 h3 { font-size: 21px;}
 p {font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; 
}



/* Global */

html    {  }
body   { background-color:#eeeeee;}

/* Sliders and Buttons */

#bannerslider   {position:relative; width: auto;   }
.bannerslider   {width:100%; height: 560px;} 
.bannerslidier img  {width:900px; height: 560px; display:none;}

#slide     {  }
.slide     {  }
#slides     {  }
.slides     {  }

/* Containers */

#wrapper     {width: 900px; margin:0px auto; background-color:ffffff;}

#top         {background-image:url('../Images/header2.png'); width:100%; padding:10px 0px; overflow:hidden;} 
#logo     {float:left; padding-left:10px;}

#social-media   {float:right; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;}
#social-media p   {color:#FFBF00; font-size:13px; margin:4px 10px 4px 0px; }
#social-media img  {width:24px; height:24px;}
#social-media ul li  {display:inline;}

#topnav     { background-color:#333333; clear:both; border-bottom: 3px #cccccc solid; overflow:hidden;}
#topnav ul    {width:100%; float:left; margin: 0px; background-color:#333333;}
#topnav ul li   { display:inline; }
#topnav ul li a   {float:left; padding:10px 20px; color:white; text-decoration:none;}
#topnav a:visited  {color:#ffffff;}
#topnav a:active  {color:#ffffff;}
#topnav a:hover   {color:#ffffff; background-color:maroon;}
#topnav a:focus   {color:#ffffff;}

#banner      {width: 100%; background-color:#555555;}
#banner bannerslider    {background-color:#333333; overflow:hidden;border:0px; }
#banner bannerslider ul {}
#banner img    {  }

#subbanner    { width:100%; background-color:#555555; padding:15px 0px; overflow:hidden;}
#subbanner h3    {color:#ffffff; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; line-height:180%; float:none;}


#content    {float:left; with:550px; padding:20px;  }
#content h1    {margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px; font-size: 32px; border-bottom: 1px #777777 solid; padding: 20px 0px;}
#content p    {margin: 16px 0px; line-height:160%; width:500px;}
#content h2    {margin: 20px 0 0 0;} 
#content img   {padding:8px;border:1px #888888 solid; margin: 8px;}

#rightside     {padding:20px; float:right; width: 300px;}
#rightside h3   {padding:22px;}
#rightside iframe  {padding-left: 25px;}
#rightside p   {margin: 8px 0; line-height:160%;}

#footer     {clear:both; background-color:#000000; width=100%; text-align:center; padding: 10px 0;} 
#footer p    {color:white; width=100%; text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Please add specifics of what you tried to make it work and what you want it to do, etc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thank you for your contribution. But, this question as it stands is too broad. If you can provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a specific issue, that would make for a better question. Also, your code snippet does not run.

Comment: If problem is js related you left out the js code. Really not clear what your issue is

Comment: Drew, thank you for your insights. I will try to keep future questions clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the multitude of jQuery plugins that are capable of doing this for you. One of the easiest is cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). You need to include jQuery in your page rather than jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile is for sites that are designed to run on a phone not a browser. Then include the cycle2 file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
```

Then add the proper markup:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="Images/bassperfect-900px.png" width="900">
    <img src="Images/chrismuskie.png" width="900">
    <img src="Images/kuntzpike.png" width="900">
    <img src="Images/unitedlumberdinner.png" width="900">
</div>
```

If you're wanting to build the site so that it's mobile friendly. the you may want to look at one of the grid systems for doing that. Personally I use Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/). It's one of the most popular.

here's a fiddle to give you an idea of what it does: http://jsfiddle.net/2c61u8a5/

Comment: Thank you Gregg, I didn't realize jQuery Mobile was that different from standard jQuery. It actually makes sense why I couldn't follow along with some other examples.

I will try this out and Bootstrap!